# What is USB HID col parameter

Tags: c#, windows, usb, hid

I have a HID device (picoLCD monochrome display), that I open in a Windows program written in C#.
I get 3 HID "instances" of my device with the following paths:

```
_devicePath = "\\\\?\\hid#vid_04d8&pid_c002&col01#7&12adec39&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
_devicePath = "\\\\?\\hid#vid_04d8&pid_c002&col02#7&12adec39&0&0001#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
_devicePath = "\\\\?\\hid#vid_04d8&pid_c002&col03#7&12adec39&0&0002#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
```

They all have the same VID and PID, but different "col". What does this parameter mean?
And why there are 3 device "descriptors" for one device?

UsbView shows only one physical device with 2 endpoints:

```
Device Descriptor:
bcdUSB:             0x0200
bDeviceClass:         0x00
bDeviceSubClass:      0x00
bDeviceProtocol:      0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:      0x08 (8)
idVendor:           0x04D8 (Microchip Technology Inc.)
idProduct:          0xC002
bcdDevice:          0x0002
iManufacturer:        0x01
iProduct:             0x02
iSerialNumber:        0x03
bNumConfigurations:   0x01

ConnectionStatus: DeviceConnected
Current Config Value: 0x01
Device Bus Speed:     Full
Device Address:       0x05
Open Pipes:              2

Endpoint Descriptor:
bEndpointAddress:     0x81  IN
Transfer Type:   Interrupt
wMaxPacketSize:     0x0040 (64)
bInterval:            0x01

Endpoint Descriptor:
bEndpointAddress:     0x01  OUT
Transfer Type:   Interrupt
wMaxPacketSize:     0x0040 (64)
bInterval:            0x01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it some sort of collection id (for example [HIDClass Hardware IDs for Top-Level Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538842%28VS.85%29.aspx))